# True Copy/Paste shortcut remapping in X11

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, xorg, copy-paste

Can I use `CMD-C` and `CMD-V` to trigger the X11 clipboard functionality?

**I do not want to remap `CMD` to send `CTRL`**. This is not just about ergonomics and muscle memory. Existing answers seem to ignore the fact that `^C` is a valid, useful character with its own meaning to lots of programs. I want to bind window manager commands (like copy/paste) to key combinations that *don't* already have decades-old conventions associated with them in popular programs, like Vim and Emacs. Something like `CMD-C`.

I want my `CTRL` key to keep doing [what it was designed to do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards).

- `CTRL-C` should continue to send an `^c` character to my terminal to kill processes
- `CTRL-V` should continue to send a `^v` character (the escape sequence in Vim)
- `CTRL-X` should continue to send a `^x` character (vim's key for "subtract `count` from number under cursor)

I want to use the `CMD` key to send commands to my window manager:

- `CMD-C` should set the highlighted text/object to the X11 `CLIPBOARD` selection.
- `CMD-V` should paste from the X11 `CLIPBOARD` buffer -no matter what is in there-- into the active target, like `CTL-V` or Edit->Paste does by default in almost every X application.

MacOS does system-wide shortcuts really well. It took some muscle memory adjustment, but now that I've realized that I can send actual control characters to my applications, I can't ever go back.

Can I configure my linux box to do the same thing, at least for copy & paste? The biggest sticking point is that `CTRL-C`/`CTRL-V` for copy/paste conflicts with vim keybindings, but generally I'd like to separate terminal control characters from window-manager command sequences.

There's a bit of [useful documentation](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) on Jamie Zawinski's site on the underlying mechanisms for how X11 handles copy/paste buffers. This is exactly the functionality I want to directly control with my keyboard. How do I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem because a lot of apps on Linux try to be smart about it and re-implement the logic on their side. Also because the concept of clipboard in X11 is broader and has several ones with different behaviors.

My setup consists of using a keybinding daemon and execute commands whenever `CMD-C` and `CMD-V` are used. The only drawback so far is `CMD-V` requires the user to release `V` first to get the paste applied. So you cannot "hold repeat" it, neither can you release `CMD` first (might trick your muscle memory at first).

First, create a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
active_window_id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
active_window_pid=$(xdotool getwindowpid "$active_window_id")
process=$(cat /proc/$active_window_pid/comm)
if [[ "$process" == "xterm" ]]; then
  xdotool key Control_L+Shift_L+v
else
  xdotool key --clearmodifiers Control_L+v
fi
```

Then, an example of valid config file for `xbindkeys`:

```
"xsel -po|xsel -bi"
  Mod4+c

"/path/to/your/script.sh"
  Release+Mod4+v
```

Example of valid config file for `sxhkd`:

```
super + c
  xsel -po|xsel -bi

@super + v
  /path/to/your/script.sh
```

You can use your WM config to map the commands too, and map additional ones, like `CMD+A` for "select all", `CMD+X` for cut, and so on.